# Error setting up the tesseract OCR in gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ocr, homebrew, tesseract

I'm trying to setup the `tesseract-ocr` gem in my rails environment. I have ran `brew install tesseract` and then ran a bundle install on the app and that all runs without errors however when starting the app (`rails s`) the following error is throw:

```
/Users/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@xxxx/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:35:in `compile': compile error: see logs at /var/folders/66/pm_j0lp94gvcj0qnlcnsx9pw0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/4239dac38f2a721e0dc5b3750d71ce2e6fa4acb6.log (CompilationError)
```

It reference the following log file:

```
g++ -dynamic -bundle -fPIC  -L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/include -o /var/folders/66/pm_j0lp94gvcj0qnlcnsx9pw0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/4239dac38f2a721e0dc5b3750d71ce2e6fa4acb6.dylib /var/folders/66/pm_j0lp94gvcj0qnlcnsx9pw0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/4239dac38f2a721e0dc5b3750d71ce2e6fa4acb6.cpp -llept 2>>/var/folders/66/pm_j0lp94gvcj0qnlcnsx9pw0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/4239dac38f2a721e0dc5b3750d71ce2e6fa4acb6.log
/var/folders/66/pm_j0lp94gvcj0qnlcnsx9pw0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/4239dac38f2a721e0dc5b3750d71ce2e6fa4acb6.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'leptonica/allheaders.h' file not found
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
```

I followed these two issues:
https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/3 and https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/21

It talks about setting ENV vars which i have done. I created a test.rb file in the initalizers folder with the following vars set:

```
ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/include' 
ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/lib'
```

However this makes no difference to the error when starting the app.

I don't understand what it means when it says update the headers. I was wondering if someone could tell me exactly what to do to get this working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this...

Just in case anyone else has a problem here's exactly how it was fixed in mine:

Firstly had to run both:

brew install tesseract

and

brew install leptonica

Then in the Gemfile NOT in an initializer you have to put both paths to the libraries as env vars:

```
ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.69/include' 
ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.69/lib'
```

Comment: Thanks, Smickie. But it doesn't work (for current versions?).
ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.00/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica /1.72/include'
ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.04.00/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.72/lib'
 Do you have any ideas? :)

Answer (score 4):

Also had the same error. I solved it by installing the `dev` packages for tesseract and leptonica.

For debian based systems

`sudo apt-get install libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev`

For redhat base systems

`sudo yum insall leptonica-devel tesseract-devel`

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue (OS X El Capitan). Fixed by downgrading tesseract with

```
brew uninstall --force tesseract
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/8ba134eda537d2cee7daa7ebdd9f728389d9c53e/Library/Formula/tesseract.rb
```

and updating xcode

```
xcode-select --install
```