# Tesseract-ocr gem issue on mac os x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, tesseract

I've installed a tesseract-ocr (0.1.5) gem.

Dependencies are also installed (tesseract/3.04.00 and leptonica/1.72)

Mac OS X Yosemity.

When I do `rake db:migrate` an error appears:

```
rake aborted!
CompilationError: compile error: see logs at /var/folders/xg/g9n7qvns5z1gsr_yjh09n1nm0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/d2f8bb8a1867b800ff8ad69a3b850c91521b3760.log
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/compilers/gcc.rb:35:in `compile'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders/c.rb:114:in `shared_object'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:in `block in build'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `build'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in `singleton_inline'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:in `inline'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:30:in `<module:BaseAPI>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:27:in `<module:C>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:25:in `<module:Tesseract>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c.rb:83:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/user/work/project/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/work/project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

In the log:

```
g++ -dynamic -bundle -fPIC    -o /var/folders/xg/g9n7qvns5z1gsr_yjh09n1nm0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/d2f8bb8a1867b800ff8ad69a3b850c91521b3760.dylib /var/folders/xg/g9n7qvns5z1gsr_yjh09n1nm0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/d2f8bb8a1867b800ff8ad69a3b850c91521b3760.cpp -ltesseract 2>>/var/folders/xg/g9n7qvns5z1gsr_yjh09n1nm0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/d2f8bb8a1867b800ff8ad69a3b850c91521b3760.log
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:171:10: error: no matching member function for call to 'SetImage'
                                api->SetImage(pix);
                                ~~~~~^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:354:8: note: candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const Pix *') would lose const qualifier
  void SetImage(Pix* pix);
       ^
/usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:341:8: note: candidate function not viable: requires 5 arguments, but 1 was provided
  void SetImage(const unsigned char* imagedata, int width, int height,
       ^
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:183:49: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'tesseract::TessResultRenderer *' with an lvalue of type 'STRING *'
                                return api->ProcessPages(filename, NULL, 0, output);
                                                                            ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:542:63: note: passing argument to parameter 'renderer' here
                    int timeout_millisec, TessResultRenderer* renderer);
                                                              ^
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.5/lib/tesseract/c/baseapi.rb:189:65: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'tesseract::TessResultRenderer *' with an lvalue of type 'STRING *'
                                return api->ProcessPage(pix, page_index, filename, NULL, 0, output);
                                                                                            ^~~~~~
/usr/local/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:558:40: note: passing argument to parameter 'renderer' here
                   TessResultRenderer* renderer);
                                       ^
```

How can I solve it?

**Update:** It's not duplicate question. It doesn't help [Error setting up the tesseract OCR in gem in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929788/error-setting-up-the-tesseract-ocr-in-gem-in-rails)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tesseract developers changed quite some stuff in version 3.0.4 and tesseract-ocr gem lost compatibility with it. The best solution I see is to downgrade for now. You may have previous versions of Tesseract installed on your mac, use `brew info tesseract` to find that out. If so, just use `brew switch`. I did `brew cleanup` recently, so I had to uninstall tesseract and install it from the old formula, like so:

```
$ brew uninstall tesseract
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/8ba134eda537d2cee7daa7ebdd9f728389d9c53e/Library/Formula/tesseract.rb
```

This will install Tesseract 3.02.02_3d that seems to be working.
You can find more info and track this issue at [tesseract-ocr repo](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/50).

Comment: This doesn't work. throws a bunch of warnings and deprecated errors

Comment: @MaheshMesta sorry, can't help, haven't working with tesseract since then. I guess you have to solve it on your own, make some hype in [that repo](https://github.com/meh/ruby-tesseract-ocr/issues/50) perhaps

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to downgrade Tesseract, an alternative quick and dirty method would be to execute Tesseract as a shell command and open the file it saves to get access to the content (note: string interpolation works in shell commands)

```
input_image = 'input.tif'
`tesseract #{input_image} output -l eng`
file = File.open('output.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log generated it showed that i was missing header file , the issue with me was that i was referencing wrong version so, 
adding these code to gem file solved the problem for me

```
ENV['CFLAGS'] = '-I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02_3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.71_1/include'
ENV['LDFLAGS'] = '-L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.02.02_3/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.71_1/lib'
```

also do check your own version of tesseract and leptonica

Comment: I wrote that this old fix doesn't help.