# error while trying to run the server after adding the gem "tesseract-ocr" rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ocr, tesseract

I was trying to make an OCR application and after adding the gem to the gemfile "tesseract-ocr" running the server, it shows the following error:

```
    /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:133:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library '/var/folders/1z/tn3pp1b90fvb5dh_7t2_kt2c0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/55a18292181116dcb44d5cd16f74500e379c7f92.dylib': dlopen(/var/folders/1z/tn3pp1b90fvb5dh_7t2_kt2c0000gn/T/.ffi-inline-501/55a18292181116dcb44d5cd16f74500e379c7f92.dylib, 5): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/liblept.4.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: liblept.4.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:90:in `block in build'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/builders.rb:87:in `build'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:54:in `singleton_inline'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ffi-inline-0.0.4.3/lib/ffi/inline/inline.rb:39:in `inline'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:34:in `<module:C>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:31:in `<module:Tesseract>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/c.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract/api.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tesseract-ocr-0.1.8/lib/tesseract-ocr.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/Desktop/project/nepal-receipt-processing-2/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `block in exec_app_rails'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rails'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.1.4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/brijesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have searched a lot in the internet but could not find the solution. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You have install tesseract lib in your computer ? (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract). This gem is an wrapper for this library.

Comment: Yes, tesseract is installed in the computer. I have tried uninstalling and installing it again but with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem was the installation of the tesseract on mac which installed the current version in which tesseract-ocr gem already lost compatibility with.

[The solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179402/tesseract-ocr-gem-issue-on-mac-os-x/33636970#33636970) shows how to install an older version of `tesseract` that is compatible with the current (as of May 2016) `tesseract-ocr 0.1.8` gem

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/8ba134eda537d2cee7daa7ebdd9f728389d9c53e/Library/Formula/tesseract.rb
```